# Button BuyNow not working with amount over 50 USD

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

Hi I made a dinamic button and it works fine only if the amount<30USD, the sandbox open's and the payment is completed, the IPN works fine too. But if I try to make a payment with amount=50.00 or above the button click goes to www.paypal.com and the payment can not be completed, neither the IPN history show that payment. Can some one help me. Thanks

Programming in C# asp.net

Here is the code:

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        Session["PayPal_Redirected"] = "True";

        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

        // strPP->SandBox
        url.Append(this.strPP + cmd);

        url.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.business));
        url.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.item_name));
        url.AppendFormat("&image_url={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.logo));
        url.AppendFormat("&no_shipping={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.no_shipping));
        url.AppendFormat("&return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.return_value));
        url.AppendFormat("&cancel_return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.cancel_return));
        url.AppendFormat("&currency_code={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.currency_code));
        url.AppendFormat("&amount={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.amount));
        url.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.item_name));
        url.AppendFormat("&item_number={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.item_number));
        url.AppendFormat("&custom={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.os0));
        url.AppendFormat("&src={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.src));
        url.AppendFormat("&sra={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.sra));
        url.AppendFormat("&notify_url={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.notify_url)); 
        Response.Redirect(url.ToString());
        return;
    }
```